# Is it possible to check or select email send option?

Tags: asp.net, email

We have a form that visitors to our site fill and send to management frequently.

After completing the form, the visitor clicks the submit form and a contents of the form  is emailed to management.

We have been tasked with providing the visitor with options of which email delivery option to send email with.

For instance, when the visitor clicks the submit button, there should be a dropdown or pulldown with three email delivery options.
1, Send email by outlook. This is the default option
2, send email by gmail, or
3, send email by yahoo

Depending on the option the visitor selected, s/he enters his/her is then allowed to send the email using his her preferred option.

Is this possible?

```
  <asp:Button ID="btnAdd" class="btn btn-warning" style="margin-left:100px;" runat="server" Text="Submit with E-mail" OnClick="Insert"  />
```

Comment: Why, it's the server that is sending the email after the form is submitted isn't it?

Comment: correct. I questioned that too. I just wanted to know if that's possible.

Comment: Then no. You cannot control that.

Comment: If the server is the one actually sending the email, then how would it get sent by Outlook? And why would they care whether it's Gmail or Yahoo? Just send the email on my behalf, who care what sends it as long as it gets there.

Comment: I completely agree with you guys. It is always good to be reassured.